# Disable drag&drop in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, drag-and-drop, projects-and-solutions

Is there a way to disable the drag&drop functionality for Solution Explorer?
Why would you ask? I'm using an wacom pen tablet for quite some years and I love
it. But when you use it in solution explorer in combination with a source control 
like TFS or AnkhSvn it's a disaster when you accidentally move a file into an 
different directory.

I currently set visual studio to prompt when files are wanted to check out, but when 
a solution/project file already is checked out then the above problems still exist.

Comment: can't we just get a damn 'confirm move' option???

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a plugin to Visual Studio 2010 that will prompt you drag & drop files in Solution Explorer: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf

Comment: too bad it's only in Pro version (50$ to get a confirmation prompt ^^)

Answer (score 9):

Sadly, turning off the drag and drop function in the Sollution Explorer is not possible.

**Edit:** The third post (by a Microsoft employee) in this [Microsoft Forum](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/5c20d208-ac72-4f05-9ad2-de3ac5fd5ac1) thread confirms this.

**Edit:** Judging from this [entry](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=110852) on Microsoft connect it also looks like this is something they have no intention of improving.

Comment: Even VSCode (another Microsoft IDE) has this feature... Visual Studio needs it too. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1414

Answer (score 3):

I looks like they have finally attempted to enable this functionality in 2017 Community (15.7.5)

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General -> "Prompt before moving files to a new location"

I say attempted because I have still had occasions where this setting hasn't displayed the dialog box, so as of V15.7.5 it is a little buggy still.