# Disabling drag and drop or ask on any drag-drop operation of files/folders VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Sometimes accidentally you move some files from somewhere to anywhere ? on Solution Explorer.

Is there any way for asking on drag & drop operations?

Or disabling drag&drop completely .

---

If you user tfs it may cause other annoying problems.

A Scenario Hard to Achieve but I Succeed!)

Suppose you don't know these moved files.

On Compile you delete these files(mostly they cause errors),if you check-in then after delete ,say goodbye to your files gone and on tfs you can't add a new file it's name used previously .

You need to get a previous version and so on...

[image]

Comment: There is no setting to do this. Plugin exists but it costs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336394/disable-dragdrop-in-solution-explorer